# Update table and refresh the table after update using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo

I have this page for searching and updating students scores using Ajax.
[image: Update result page]

I have the following JavaScript code to save scores using ajax when 'Save' button is clicked:

```
        function saveScores() {
            const id = arguments[0];
            var form = document.querySelector("#scores-form");
            var studRegNo = form.querySelector('input[name="studRegNo'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit1 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit1'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit2 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit2'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit3 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit3'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit4 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit4'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit5 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit5'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit6 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit6'+id+'"]').value;

            const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                toast: true,
                showConfirmButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#10393b',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                cancelButtonText: 'No',
            })
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'question',
                title: 'Do you want to save changes'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.dismiss !== 'cancel') {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../include/ajaxInsert.php',
                        data: {
                            studRegNo: studRegNo,
                            userId: <?php echo $userId; ?>,
                            visit1: visit1,
                            visit2: visit2,
                            visit3: visit3,
                            visit4: visit4,
                            visit5: visit5,
                            visit6: visit6,
                            id: id,
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data!="empty"){
                                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                                    toast: true,
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 2500,
                                    timerProgressBar: true,
                                    didOpen: (toast) => {
                                        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                                        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                                    }
                                })
                                Toast.fire({
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    title: 'Changes saved successfully.'
                                })
                            }
                            else{
                                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                                    toast: true,
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 1500,
                                    timerProgressBar: true,
                                })
                                Toast.fire({
                                    icon: 'warning',
                                    title: 'No changes made.'
                                })
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            console.error(xhr);
                        },
                    });
                }
            })
            
        }
```

- I can successfully search students using PHP/PDO and display the result
- I can successfully save the scores without refreshing the page

What I want is to refresh and update the row affected(Total) or the table data after saving the scores without refreshing the page.
Is that possible? and any solution to do that is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to sum up visit1 through 6 and set the innerHtml of the total element to the result in your success function. You didnt give the id of the total element so i assumed it was total.

```js
        function saveScores() {
            const id = arguments[0];
            var form = document.querySelector("#scores-form");
            var studRegNo = form.querySelector('input[name="studRegNo'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit1 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit1'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit2 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit2'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit3 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit3'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit4 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit4'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit5 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit5'+id+'"]').value;
            var visit6 = form.querySelector('input[name="visit6'+id+'"]').value;

            const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                toast: true,
                showConfirmButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#10393b',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                cancelButtonText: 'No',
            })
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'question',
                title: 'Do you want to save changes'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.dismiss !== 'cancel') {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../include/ajaxInsert.php',
                        data: {
                            studRegNo: studRegNo,
                            userId: <?php echo $userId; ?>,
                            visit1: visit1,
                            visit2: visit2,
                            visit3: visit3,
                            visit4: visit4,
                            visit5: visit5,
                            visit6: visit6,
                            id: id,
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data!="empty"){
                                document.getElementById("total").innerHtml = visit1 + visit2 + visit3 + visit4 + visit5 + visit6;
                                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                                    toast: true,
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 2500,
                                    timerProgressBar: true,
                                    didOpen: (toast) => {
                                        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                                        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                                    }
                                })
                                Toast.fire({
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    title: 'Changes saved successfully.'
                                })
                            }
                            else{
                                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                                    toast: true,
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 1500,
                                    timerProgressBar: true,
                                })
                                Toast.fire({
                                    icon: 'warning',
                                    title: 'No changes made.'
                                })
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            console.error(xhr);
                        },
                    });
                }
            })
            
        }
```